# catch http errors in Observable.interval()

Tags: angular, angular5

I have a piece of block that runs once an hour to a given url. Basically, now if the url is not found or generally responds with error 500, I get the error message. The application makes use of service workers but works fine if the url provided exists (404/500 triggers the message below):

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: An unknown error occurred when fetching the script.
TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: An unknown error occurred when fetching the script.
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:831)
    at eval (zone.js:741)
    at eval (zone.js:757)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:391)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:4760)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:390)
    at Zone.run (zone.js:150)
    at eval (zone.js:889)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4751)
```

in my console. How can I catch the error gracefully?

```
Observable.interval(3000)
      .subscribe((data) => {
         this.http.get('http://localhost:87887/profile/1/') // doesnt exist
           .subscribe((data) => {
             this.pingStream.next(true);
           },
           err => {

             if (err.status == 500){
              this.pingStream.next(false);
             }
             else{
               this.pingStream.next(true);
             }

           }
           );
      });
```

Comment: what version of angular/rxjs are you using?

Comment: When the call fails do you want `interval(3000)` to keep emitting or you want to stop the chain?

Comment: To keep emitting @martin and I am angular 5.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep your subscription logic separate from your async logic.

```
Observable.interval(3000)
      .pipe(
       mergeMap(() => make http call),
       catchError( e => this.pingStream.next(false)),
       map((data) => this.pingStream.next(true))
      )
      .subscribe();
```

`mergemap` will take your interval on every 3 seconds and make a http call to whatever service you want.
`catchError` will gracefully handle that error for you
`map` will take the successful call and do something with that value.
`subscribe()` just activates the observable.

Comment: hey @Mike Tung, can you plugin my code into yours as I am getting a buttload of compile errors on mergeMap and catchEerror blogs?

Comment: You are using `map` where a `tap` would be the correct option

Comment: Furthermore, this wont fulfill all of OPs requirements

Answer (score 0):

If you want the chain to continue after an error so `interval(3000)` keeps emitting you'll have to put `catchError` inside `concatMap` (or `mergeMap` will work as well). Then it depends what you want to do when an error happens. You can just ignore it by returning `EMPTY` or turn it to a `next` notification:

```
import { EMPTY } from 'rxjs';
...

// Assuming you're using RxJS 6
interval(3000).pipe(
  concatMap(() => this.http.get('http://localhost:87887/profile/1/').pipe(
    catchError(error => {
      if (err.status == 500){
        this.pingStream.next(false);
      } else {
        this.pingStream.next(true);
      }
      return EMPTY;
    })
  ))
).subscribe(data => this.pingStream.next(true));
```